# undocumented ERB syntax: <%=h ... %>

Tags: ruby, erb

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/erb/rdoc/classes/ERB.html lists a set of Recognized Tags - however, this list seems incomplete; for one thing it's missing the dash variant (`<%- ... -%>`, which suppresses line breaks IIRC).

Now I've [come across](http://marklunds.com/articles/one/313) another seemingly undocumented variant:

```
<%=h some_variable %>
<%= link_to h(some_variable) ... %>
```

Google wouldn't tell me what that was all about; can anyone point me to an explanation?

Comment: It's documented here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/erb/rdoc/

Comment: @a'r: Can you be more specific? Your link is similar to mine, so I'm not sure where to look...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not an ERB syntax. It is `<%= ... %>` and inside it is calling the [`ERB::Util.h`method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/erb/rdoc/classes/ERB/Util.html#M000869)

Answer (score 3):

`h` here is just a regular method, in fact it's an alias for `html_escape`.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/erb/rdoc/classes/ERB/Util.html#M000868

Comment: and html escape is done automatically in Rails 3..so no need to use this in Rails 3